# What is the EBP register pointing to when the main function executes? (Intel x82 architecture)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I know that during a function call, the EBP register is pointing to the first value that the called function pushes onto the stack. But when the main function is called for the first time, what is the EBP register pointing to? Is it the first local variable that is pushed onto the stack by the main function?

Comment: Actually, if `ebp` is used as a frame pointer, it usually points at the *old* `ebp`, since the normal function entry code is `push ebp; mov ebp, esp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined where `ebp` points to when the function is entered. Function prologue (which is part of the function) makes `ebp` point to stack frame, although the prologue can be omitted if it is not needed or can do anything else with `ebp` as long as it restores the value when returning. `main` is not different in this.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `ebp` before the `main()` is initialized by the operating system, so you need to say what OS you are using.

Speaking about Linux and the `libc`, there is function prior to `main()` which is called `_start`. But, before `_start`, the position of `ebp` and `esp` are decided by the Linux kernel when allocating the stack. And, most of the time, the default value is added to an offset in order to implement ASLR (Address-Space Layout Randomization).

Comment: Initial `ebp` is undefined in the ABI, but the linux kernel sets it to zero.

Comment: @Jester: It is undefined in the ABI, but certainly not when `main()` is running. Or you would have a real problem...

Comment: It is undefined even upon entry into `main`, and no, that doesn't pose a problem, because any function that wants a frame pointer has to set it up for itself. See @StenSoft's answer.